# Is there a way to make a fluid collide with another fluid?

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I want 2 fluid simulations to collide together. However, there isnt an option to have a fluid be both a domain and effector. How would I make 2 fluids collide?

Here is an example:

The picture isnt actually colliding, it's a mirror. How would I make it so that they do collide with each other?

[image]

Comment: There is not a native solution I guess, but you can try "Liquid" from particles driven by smoke that can collide ...  so can be usefull in some situations https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0Tz1U6A5vI Here Liquid, it is not colliding but looks like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLwCFOsgYrI or try Fluid Particles https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxnagkrLzJY

Comment: Do you mean "collide" as in the picture? Or collide then mix together?

Comment: I mean collide as in the picture. They will have the same materials so they cannot mix. I want them to interact with each other, and respond to each other's movements.

Comment: 2 way effect interactions are not in mantaflow, like a ship floats on water and the water is affected by the ship as well. there is other fluidsim software that might do it but its not free.

Comment: Well that disappointing, not only because I can't do it, but also because I wasted 50 reputation on this bounty lol.

Comment: that shouldnt be a problem, you didnt reward a solution so i believe your points stay